# Install RequestTracker (RT) on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, perl, installation, request-tracker

Is it possible to install the latest RT on Windows Server?

I've found some installers online for previous versions, but can't find any tutorials for the current version.

Currently trying to do something with Cygwin, but I've got a feeling I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

It is [**explicitly not supported on Windows**](http://bestpractical.com/rt/requirements.html).

RT requires tight integration with a sendmail-compatible mail server, and makes many assumptions about tools such as those mentioned elsethread.

Answer (score 3):

RT has a massive collection of perl dependencies, plus library dependencies on GD, GraphViz, GnuPGP et al; it's challenging to install even on UNIX, where the developers have tested it. If you want to run RT, run it on a recent Linux.